# Passing credentials to Azure resource manager template

Tags: azure, azure-resource-manager, azure-rm-template

According to Microsoft documentation [settings-vs-protectedsettings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/extensions/dsc-template#settings-vs-protectedsettings) the Properties listed under protectedSettings are encrypted with a certificate and are not shown in plain text in the settings file on the VM. However, my deployment fails with the error below

> new-azResourceGroupDeployment : 00:08:49 - Resource
>   Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/extensions
>   'DI-DEV-UKW-DB1/Microsoft.Powershell.DSC' failed with message '{
>   "status": "Failed",   "error": {
>       "code": "ResourceDeploymentFailure",
>       "message": "The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.",
>       "details": [
>         {
>           "code": "VMExtensionProvisioningError",
>           "message": "VM has reported a failure when processing extension 'Microsoft.Powershell.DSC'. Error message: \"The DSC
>   Extension received an incorrect input: Compilation errors occurred
>   while  processing configuration 'SQLConfig'. Please review the errors
>   reported in error stream and modify your configuration code
>   appropriately. System.InvalidOperationException error processing
>   property  'PsDscRunAsCredential' OF TYPE 'SqlServerRole': Converting
>   and storing encrypted passwords as plain text is not recommended. For
>   more information on securing credentials in MOF file, please refer to 
>   MSDN blog: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393729\nAt
>   C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.77.0.0\DSCWork\sqlserverconfig.ps1.19\sqlserverconfig.ps1:110
>   char:9\n+    SqlServerRole Converting and storing encrypted passwords
>   as plain text is not recommended. For more information on securing
>   credentials in MOF file, please refer to MSDN blog: 
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393729 Cannot find path
>   'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\DSC' because it does not
>   exist. Cannot find path 
>   'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\DSC' because it does not
>   exist. System.InvalidOperationException error processing property
>   'PsDscRunAsCredential' OF TYPE 'SqlServerLogin': Converting and 
>   storing encrypted passwords as plain text is not recommended. For more
>   information on securing credentials in MOF file, please refer to MSDN
>   blog: http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393729\nAt 
>   C:\Packages\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.77.0.0\DSCWork\sqlserverconfig.ps1.19\sqlserverconfig.ps1:100
>   char:9\n+   SqlServerLogin Converting and storing encrypted passwords
>   as plain text  is not recommended. For more information on securing
>   credentials in MOF file, please refer to MSDN blog:
>   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=393729 Cannot find path 
>   'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\DSC' because it does not
>   exist. Cannot find path
>   'HKLM:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\PowerShell\3\DSC' because it does not
>   exist.\n\nAnother common error is to  specify parameters of type
>   PSCredential without an explicit type. Please be sure to use a typed
>   parameter in DSC Configuration, for example:\n\n    configuration
>   Example {\n         param([PSCredential] $UserAccount)\n        ...\n 
>   }.\nPlease correct the input and retry executing the extension.\"."
>         }
>       ]   } }

please see the link for my code [Scripts](https://paste.ee/p/gaDOx)

Comment: you sure this configuration works locally? this is a pretty generic error, the way you pass credentials is okay

Comment: You mean the DSC?..Yes I tested it with test-dscresource on the server I am trying to deploy it to..

Comment: no, test-dscresource doesnt really test your configuration... can you run it manually on the test server?

Comment: Strange.. the Add_ServerRole_sysadmin fails with
 PowerShell DSC resource MSFT_SqlServerRole  failed to execute Set-TargetResource functionality with error message: System.InvalidOperationException: 
Failed to drop member 'sa' to the server role named 'sysadmin' on 'XX-dev-ukw-db1\MSSQLSERVER'. ---> 
System.Management.Automation.MethodInvocationException: Exception calling "DropMember" with "1" argument(s): "Drop member failed for ServerRole 
'sysadmin'. " ---> Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.FailedOperationException: Drop member failed for ServerRole 'sysadmin'.  --->

Comment: The configuration should be adding the sysadmin role not removing..

Answer (score 1):

in this case the error was due to dsc trying to drop the SA user. this is because you misconfigured it. Reference: https://github.com/PowerShell/SqlServerDsc#sqlserverrole

you need to use `MembersToInclude`, instead of members, as members will replace existing members with whatever you specify.

i'd suggest trying to compile it locally with the exact same inputs (on the same vm) and see if it works. Another way to test this - remove resources one by one, that way you can hopefully narrow it down to the specific failing resource. another thing: try doing this:

```
    [System.Management.Automation.PSCredential]$DomainCreds = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ("domain_name\$($AdminCredentials.UserName)", $AdminCredentials.Password)
```

and use that $domainCreds variable in your config, not adminCredentials.

Comment: The deployment via the ar template still fails. However, the local deployment using start-dscconfiguration works. https://paste.ee/p/yzHjT

Comment: can you get logs from inside the windows vm and post them here? c:\windowsazure\plugins or package or logs something liket that

Comment: Please see the link. 
https://paste.ee/p/Hajxy for the content of  C:\WindowsAzure\Logs\Plugins\Microsoft.Powershell.DSC\2.77.0.0\DscExtensionHandler.1.20190221-201041.

Comment: yeah, nothing new, unfortunately. check updated answer